# Prove that $\frac{\sec^3θ}{\sec^2θ - 1} + \frac{\csc^3θ}{\csc^2θ - 1} = \secθ \cscθ (\secθ + \cscθ)$

Tags: trigonometry

Kindly guide me to prove this

$$\frac{\sec^3θ}{\sec^2θ - 1} + \frac{\csc^3θ}{\csc^2θ-1} = \secθ \cscθ (\secθ + \cscθ)$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write $\sec\theta=\dfrac{1}{\cos\theta}$, so
$$
\frac{\sec^3\theta}{\sec^2\theta-1}=
\frac{\dfrac{1}{\mathstrut\cos^3\theta}}{\dfrac{1}{\cos^2\theta}-1}=
\frac{1}{\cos^3\theta}\frac{\cos^2\theta}{1-\cos^2\theta}=
\frac{1}{\cos\theta\sin^2\theta}
$$
Similarly, the second term is
$$
\frac{\csc^3\theta}{\csc^2\theta-1}=
\frac{1}{\sin\theta\cos^2\theta}
$$
and their sum cam be written
$$
\frac{\cos\theta+\sin\theta}{\sin^2\theta\cos^2\theta}
$$

Now massage also the right-hand side in a similar fashion

Answer (score -1):

Consider:
\begin{align}
\frac{\sec^3θ}{\sec^2θ - 1} + \frac{\csc^3θ}{\csc^2θ-1} &= \frac{\sec^3θ}{\tan^{2}\theta} + \frac{\csc^3θ}{\cot^{2}\theta} \\
&= \frac{1}{\cos^{3}\theta}\cdot \frac{\cos^{2}\theta}{\sin^{2}\theta} + \frac{1}{\sin^{3}\theta}\cdot \frac{\sin^{2}\theta}{\cos^{2}\theta} \\
&= \csc\theta \sec\theta \, ( \sec\theta + \csc\theta )
\end{align}
since $\sec^{2}\theta = \tan^{2}\theta + 1$ and $\cot^{2}\theta + 1 = \csc^{2}\theta$.

Comment: Can you please show the steps. I am unable to simplify the middle step